# Undefined mixin 'grid-toggle': SGS 1.2.1

Tags: singularitygs

I'm currently on the 1.2.1 version of SGS and finding that the grid-toggle mixin is failing for me.

According to the current WIKI docs it states:

> If you'd like to be able to toggle your grid on and off, the `grid-toggle` mixin can be used. The grid-toggle mixin should not be used from within a selector; it will write its own.

To me the most important part is the entire 2nd sentence which states…

> The grid-toggle mixin SHOULD NOT be used from within a selector.

When I run `compass:dist` I get the following…

> Undefined mixin 'grid-toggle'

Here's a codeshare of my current SGS Sass file http://codeshare.io/Ek0sH and here's another codeshare of my gems in use w/versions of each listed. http://codeshare.io/NEzzr

Answer (score 1):

`grid-toggle` has been removed.

Sam 'Snugug' Richards, the maintainer of Singularity, claims that it never worked properly anyway.

The docs are to be updated.

See the corresponding discussion: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues/195